# Return multiple lists from comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there any way in Python to return multiple lists from a comprehension?

I want to do something to the effect of:

```
x,y = [i,(-1*j) for (i,j) in enumerate(range(10))]
# x = [0 .. 9]
# y = [0 .. -9]
```

that's a dumb example, but I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Probably but I can't think of a practical reason of why you would want to.

Comment: @IanAuld you cant see a practical reason for wanting to seperate your x's and y's ? (maybe for plotting in certain libs?)

Comment: It would probably be more readable and more maintainable to do it separately. There's no need to stick everything on one line.

Answer (score 2):

```
x,y =zip(* [(i,(-1*j)) for (i,j) in enumerate(range(10))] )
```

you just unzip the list

```
xy = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
x,y = zip(*xy)
# x = (1,3,5)
# y = (2,4,6)
```

Comment: The return types of both of these are tuples not lists

Comment: it will give tuples, not lists, but it's the right idea

Comment: Sort of. A major difference being mutable != immutable.

Comment: maybe /.... usually people don't need mutable for this type of problem ... although its easy enough to make it mutable ...

Comment: Just wrap with `map(list, )`, as in, `x, y = map(list, zip(...))` and it will produce `list`s, not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the list comprehension:

```
>>> x,y=range(0,10), range(0,-10,-1)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Or you could do:

```
>>> x,y=map(list, zip(*[(e,-e) for e in range(10)]))
```

Comment: Note: `range` only returns `list` on Py2; on Py3, it's a special `range` object that would need to be wrapped in the `list` constructor to make an actual, mutable `list`. But yes, if the problem is as simple as given, best to avoid the complexity of generating paired values and unpairing them when it's easier to generate unpaired values directly. And if mutability is not needed, using the raw Py3 `range` would often be better than a mutable `list` (Py2 `xrange` isn't quite as good as a drop-in replacement, even if you don't need mutability).